# Can you partition on unix time (INT) in BigQuery? If so, How?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Currently I'm working on a task in Airflow that loads CSV files to BigQuery where the time column is unix time (e.g., 1658371030).

The Airflow operator I'm using is [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery.GCSToBigQueryOperator) where one of the params passed is schema_fields. If I define the time field in schema_fields value to be:

```
schema_fields = [
{"name": "UTCTimestamp", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
....,
{"name": "OtherValue", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
]
```

Will BigQuery automatically detect that the unix time is INT and cast it to utc timestamp?

If it can't, how can we partition on a unix time (INT) in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried making a table with partitioned tables using airflow, Can you try adding this parameter to your code(looking at your post UTCTimestamp is the only field applicable for partitioning):

```
time_partitioning={'type': 'MONTH', 'field': 'UTCTimestamp'}
```

For your reference `type` Specifies the type of time partitioning to perform and a required parameter for time portioning and `field`  is the field name that is going to be partitioned.

Below is the dag file I have used for testing creating partitioned table.

**My full code:**

```
import os
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime
dag_id = "TimeStampTry"

DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_DATASET_NAME", '<yourDataSetName>')
TABLE_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_TABLE_NAME", '<yourTableNameHere>')


with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=["SampleReplicate"],
) as dag:
   load_csv = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bigquery_example2',
    bucket='<yourBucketNameHere>',
    source_objects=['timestampsamp.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'Name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'date', 'type': 'TIMESTAMP', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'Device', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    time_partitioning={'type': 'MONTH', 'field': 'date'}
    ,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dag=dag,
)
```

**timestampsamp.csv content:**
[image]

**Screenshot of the table created in BQ:**
[image]
[image]

As you can see the table type is set to partitioned.

Also please visit this article about [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timepartitioning) Rest reference for more details about the parameters and its descriptions.

Comment: Thanks Nestor for the detailed explanation!

Comment: You are welcome!, If you find this answer works for you,  you can accept this answer to mark the question solved. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.